# Два ResultSet в сервлете

Tags: java

такой вот вопрос, можно ли использовать два `ResultSet` в одном сервлете или нет? При использовании второго `ResultSet` выдает ошибку: `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ResultSet not positioned properly, perhaps you need to call next`

Сервлет:

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    request.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");

    List<Pkvzdcsql> pkvzdcsqlS = new ArrayList<Pkvzdcsql>();
    List<Pkvzdcsql> pkvzdcsqlDvmS = new ArrayList<Pkvzdcsql>();

    try {

        String osdch = request.getParameter("osdch").replace("*", "%").toUpperCase();
        String osdi = request.getParameter("osdi").replace("*", "%").toUpperCase();
        String nceh = request.getParameter("nceh").replace("*", "%").toUpperCase();

        int page = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("page"));
        int count = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("count"));
        while ((nceh.length() < 3) && (nceh.length() != 0)) {
            nceh = " " + nceh;
        }

        Integer pages;
        try {
            pages = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("pages"));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            pages = 25;
        }

        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(
                "with pkvzdc as (\n"
                + "      select \n"
                + "         nceh,osdch_t,osdch_r,osdch_c,(osdch_c||osdch_r) as osdch,\n"
                + "         osdk_t,osdk_r,osdk_c,(osdk_c||osdk_r) as osdk,\n"
                + "         osdi_t,osdi_r,osdi_c,(osdi_c||osdi_r) as osdi,\n"
                + "         kol,koli,kolzd,dvm\n"
                + "      from clippersql.pkvzdcsql\n"
                + "         where (osdch_c||osdch_r = '" + osdch + "' or '" + osdch + "' = '')\n"
                + "         and (osdi_c||osdi_r = '" + osdi + "' or '" + osdi + "' = '')\n"
                + "         and (nceh = '" + nceh + "' or '" + nceh + "' = '')\n"
                + "      order by nceh, osdch_t, osdch_r, osdch_c, osdk_t, osdk_r, osdk_c, osdi_t, osdi_r, osdi_c \n"
                + "      limit " + pages + " offset " + count + "),\n");

        ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            Pkvzdcsql pkvzdcsql = new Pkvzdcsql();

            pkvzdcsql.setOsdch(rs.getString("osdch"));
            pkvzdcsql.setOsdi(rs.getString("osdi"));
            pkvzdcsql.setOsdk(rs.getString("osdk"));
            pkvzdcsql.setDvm(rs.getDate("dvm"));
            pkvzdcsql.setNaim_ch(rs.getString("naim_ch"));
            pkvzdcsql.setNaim_k(rs.getString("naim_k"));
            pkvzdcsql.setNaim_i(rs.getString("naim_i"));
            pkvzdcsql.setKol(rs.getString("kol").replaceAll("\\.(.*?)0+$", ".$1").replaceAll("\\.$", ""));
            pkvzdcsql.setKoli(rs.getString("koli").replaceAll("\\.(.*?)0+$", ".$1").replaceAll("\\.$", ""));
            pkvzdcsql.setKolzd(rs.getString("kolzd").replaceAll("\\.(.*?)0+$", ".$1").replaceAll("\\.$", ""));
            pkvzdcsql.setOsdch_count(rs.getString("osdch_count"));
            pkvzdcsql.setOsdk_count(rs.getString("osdk_count"));
            pkvzdcsql.setNceh(rs.getString("nceh"));
            pkvzdcsqlS.add(pkvzdcsql);
        }

        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        String query2 = "select dvm \n"
                + "from clippersql.pkvzdcsql\n"
                + "limit 1";
        ResultSet rs2 = statement.executeQuery(query2);
        while (rs2.next()) {
            Pkvzdcsql oneDvm = new Pkvzdcsql();
            oneDvm.setDvm(rs.getDate("dvm"));
            pkvzdcsqlDvmS.add(oneDvm);
        }

        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("/searchViewPkvzds.jsp");
        int size = pkvzdcsqlS.size();
        request.setAttribute("page", page);
        request.setAttribute("osdch", osdch.replace("%", "*"));
        request.setAttribute("nceh", nceh.replace("%", "*"));
        request.setAttribute("osdi", osdi.replace("%", "*"));

        request.setAttribute("size", size);
        request.setAttribute("pages", pages);
        request.setAttribute("count", count);
        int counts = 1000;
        request.setAttribute("counts", counts);
        request.setAttribute("pkvzdcsqlS", pkvzdcsqlS);
        request.setAttribute("pkvzdcsqlDvmS", pkvzdcsqlDvmS);
        view.forward(request, response);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот здесь у Вас скорее всего ошибка:

```
    while (rs2.next()) {
        Pkvzdcsql oneDvm = new Pkvzdcsql();
        oneDvm.setDvm(rs.getDate("dvm"));
        pkvzdcsqlDvmS.add(oneDvm);
    }
```

посмотрите какой ResultSet вы дергаете.
Именно по-этому нужно давать обдуманные названия переменным.

Comment: вот этот  `ResultSet rs2 = statement.executeQuery(query2);` он отвечает за второй запрос, без него первый отрабатывает на ура

Comment: пардон, просто нужно быть внимательным, вот так вчера час потратил, ничего не нашел, а сегодня вот увидел что тут `oneDvm.setDvm(rs.getDate("dvm"));` должен быть `rs2.getDate("dvm"))`.